# Is it possible to use all angularjs modules with browserify?

Tags: angularjs, npm, browserify

I found a module named angular-timeline and did
npm install angular-timeline --save then 
require('angular-timeline')

```
var angular = require('angular');
require('angular-ui-router');
require('angular-ui-bootstrap');
require('angular-timeline');
angular.module('rajRanjan', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap','angular-timeline'])

//configuration block of the app
angular.module('rajRanjan').config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
.state('dashboard', {
    url: "/dashboard",
    controller: "dashboardController",
    templateUrl: "app/components/dashboard/dashboard.html"


})
.state('projects', {
    url: "/projects",
    controller: "projectController",
    templateUrl: "app/components/projects/project.html"


});
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");
});
```

but when i ran browserify then it is giving me error

events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'angular-timeline' from '/Users/alepord/github/rajranjan.github.io/app'

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 'npm install angular-module --save', try 'npm install angular-timeline --save'.

[Angular timeline npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-timeline)

**Edit--**

From the [browserify-handbook](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook)

> If there is no package.json or no "main" field, index.js is assumed.

Since the package angular-timeline does not provide any of those, you must require from the whole path.

```
 require('angular-timeline/dist/angular-timeline');
```

Comment: From angular module I meant installing angular-timeline only. I have edited it.

Comment: Oh, now I got it. 

Try this require('angular-timeline/dist/angular-timeline');

Comment: Accordingly to browserify documentation, "If there is no package.json or no "main" field, index.js is assumed". 

Since angular-timeline does not have a index.js or main specified in package.json, you must require from the path.